Modifying storage and calling extrinsics for overhead benchmark
I am trying to implement the Overhead benchmark command for our parachain
Here is the code I have already:
                BenchmarkCmd::Overhead(cmd) => runner.sync_run(|config| {
                    let bob = Sr25519Keyring::Bob.pair();
                    let partials = new_partial(&config)?;
                    let ext_builder = RemarkBuilder::new(partials.client.clone(), bob.clone());
                    let inh = para_benchmark_inherent_data().unwrap();

                    cmd.run(
                        config,
                        partials.client,
                        inh,
                        Vec::new(),
                        &ext_builder,
                    )
                }),

So far so good, but I would need to set some storage items, such as some specific balance for Bob (and other pallet storages), in order to call the overhead logic
What I tried is to make a specific runtime api method where I call the needed extrinsics/storage operations, but somehow these changes were not there when the benchmark is being executed:
                BenchmarkCmd::Overhead(cmd) => runner.sync_run(|config| {
                    let bob = Sr25519Keyring::Bob.pair();
                    let partials = new_partial(&config)?;
                    let ext_builder = RemarkBuilder::new(partials.client.clone(), bob.clone());
                    let inh = para_benchmark_inherent_data().unwrap();

                    let state_version = Cli::runtime_version().state_version();
                    let block: Block = generate_genesis_block(&*config.chain_spec, state_version)?;
                    let bob_acc  = bob.clone().public();
                    partials.client.runtime_api().set_up_insufficient_fee_payment(block.hash(), bob_acc.into()).unwrap();

                    cmd.run(
                        config,
                        partials.client,
                        inh,
                        Vec::new(),
                        &ext_builder,
                    )
                }),


It is probably because the storage state is set to genesis when the benchmark is executed.
How can I easily modify the storage, or call some extrinsics for the overhead benchmarking?
